# Cannot find name 'componentDidUpdate' or what ever component on React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can I use **componentDidUpdate** or what ever component with Typescript? My program does not find the function.

But for example **UseEffect()** works well.

Comment: You have included no code to look at, so it is hard to tell, but your reference to `useEffect` makes it sound like your using function based components, as opposed to class based components. While this is good (classes will go away someday), the lifecycle method you mention is *only* available in class based components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentDidUpdate` is only available on class components. For example:

```
class A extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        // works
    }
}
```

Hooks like `useEffect` are only available on functional components. For example:

```
function B() {
    useEffect(() => {
        // works
    })
}
```

You cannot use lifecycle methods on functional components, and you cannot use hooks on class components.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSGcAvnGVBCHAORSoYsCwAUL2gBsUhQnACCcJAA8YSAHYATUcnQwAdAGEmkOfPg5ecI3DTaIuuTAAiwBQFUwClLIAUASlyHj3gPQ+4AO7QANaEXkY0vJF8PGT4chjA5nAAQu6ePN5EpBRUMC7pALwAfBnevv5BUKHhtG5RQA)

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidUpdate()` is a lifecycle method used strictly in a Class based Component. The reason `useEffect()` is working for you is more than likely because you're using a Function Component. That's my best guess without actually seeing your code. Using TypeScript in tandem *shouldn't* have any effect on this.

If you're trying to perform changes in your component based on updated props (or state) using `useEffect()`, you can add a dependency as your second parameter;

```
useEffect(() => {
   ...act accordingly here...
}, [props.isActive])
```

The code above will check if the `isActive` prop supplied updated and if so, will run the code in the `useEffect()` hook.
More on [Effect Hooks here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Here's some material on the [difference](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) between the two